# Getting funcap plugin work in IDA pro

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

I am trying to use [funcap plugin](https://github.com/deresz/funcap) in IDA pro 6.1. However, after loading the plugin (with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and pressing the debugger's run button, it returns me:

```
Internal error 30191
```

Any idea what is the problem?

P.S.: I have tried with both Python 2.6 and 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

By any chance do you have the IDAStealth plugin installed? If so, do you have SEH debugging support features enabled?

As per the bugfix for the plugin:

```
Bugfix: If any of the SEH debugging support features was used an "internal error 30191" would be raised in IDA as soon as the exception occurred in the debuggee
```

http://newgre.net/idastealth

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, no. I don't.